Sagemaker studio execution role deny policy not working
In my Sagemaker Studio we have a default execution role that is assigned to all users. Users are using the Jupyter Server app.
We have a policy attached to the role that should deny the creation of a notebook instance with several instance types, one of which is ml.t3.medium. I expect this to prevent from creating a notebook in sagemaker studio using the ml.t3.medium instance type, but I can create a notebook within sagemaker studio with that instance type. The policy is below, I have tried ForAnyValue and ForAllValues in the condition
{
    "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": [
        "sagemaker:CreateSpace",
        "sagemaker:CreateDomain",
        "sagemaker:UpdateDomain",
        "sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob",
        "sagemaker:CreateProcessingJob",
        "sagemaker:CreateNotebookInstance",
        "sagemaker:UpdateNotebookInstance",
        "sagemaker:CreateApp",
        "sagemaker:StartNotebookInstance"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:sagemaker:*:*:notebook-instance/*",
        "arn:aws:sagemaker:*:*:processing-job/*",
        "arn:aws:sagemaker:*:*:domain/*",
        "arn:aws:sagemaker:*:*:training-job/*",
        "arn:aws:sagemaker:*:*:space/*/*"
    ],
    "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
            "sagemaker:InstanceTypes": [
                "ml.p3.*",
                "*.16x*",
                "*.24x*",
                "*.48x*",
                "ml.g5.12xlarge",
                "ml.t3.medium"
            ]
        }
    }
}


Changing condition to StringNotLike worked
{
    "Action": [
        "sagemaker:CreateApp"
    ],
    "Resource": [
        "*"
    ],
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Sid": "BlockSagemakerOtherThanT3",
    "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringNotLike": {
            "sagemaker:InstanceTypes": [
                "ml.t3.medium",
                "ml.t3.xlarge",
                "system",
                "default"
            ]
        }
    }
}

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/issues/1499#issuecomment-850381743
